# Running Payara Micro from Maven: "Deployed 0 archive(s)"

Tags: maven, microprofile, payara-micro

I am trying to set up an Eclipe MicroProfile Application with Maven. I generated the archive with the MicroProfile Starter at start.microprofile.io, which generates the following pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.javahippie.playground</groupId>
  <artifactId>config_api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
      <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>payara-micro</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>fish.payara.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>payara-micro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>bundle</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <payaraVersion>5.191</payaraVersion>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

I tried to start the application from Maven, as stated by the documentation: `mvn package payara-micro:start`, and Payara does not seem to find my packaged WAR file:

```
[2019-04-07T10:21:56.358+0200] [] [INFORMATION] [] [PayaraMicro] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1554625316358] [levelValue: 800] Deployed 0 archive(s)
```

However, if I run this command from my projects' `target` folder, everything works as expected: `java -jar config_api-microbundle.jar`.

I would prefer bundling and starting the application with maven a lot, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generated Payara Micro application from https://start.microprofile.io can be started using bundled Payara Micro uber jar with the following instructions :

> The generation of the executable jar file can be performed by issuing  the following command
>
> ```
> mvn clean package
> ```
>
> This will create an executable jar file **demo-microbundle.jar** within  the *target* maven folder. This can be started by executing the  following command
>
> ```
> java -jar target/demo-microbundle.jar
> ```
>
> To launch the test page, open your browser at the following URL
>
> http://localhost:8080/index.html

And If you want to start Payara Micro instance from war, You may set `deployWar` property value to `true`:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>fish.payara.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>payara-micro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <payaraVersion>5.191</payaraVersion>
      <deployWar>true</deployWar>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```